# Creating names scoped based on join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, named-scope

I need filter 'apps' in my rails project based on whether they support iphone. I am trying to create a named scope for this purpose but I am getting the following error.

```
app/models/app.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
app/models/app.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
app/controllers/apps_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

app.rb

```
named_scope :with_iphone_support,
              joins: :version,
              conditions: {:versions.any{ |v| v.iphone_support == true}}
```

Comment: Is this Rails 2.x or a more modern version?

Comment: @tadman it is 4.x, so I'm guess in need a scope not named_scope

Comment: Wasn't sure if you were dealing with a legacy application or not. The new `scope` method is a lot more flexible and worth checking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it should look something like this for Rails 2:

```
named_scope :with_iphone_support,
  joins: :version,
  conditions: { versions: { iphone_support: true } }
```

It's not possible to pass in a block to something like that.

Rails 3.x and newer use the `scope` + `where` method for defining scopes.

Answer (score 1):

conditions expects a hash, not a block.

Try this:

```
named_scope :with_iphone_support,
             conditions: 'exists(select * from versions where iphone_support = 1 and app_id = apps.id)'
```

Comment: my bad, I forget to delete the extra {}